# elasticsearch custom tokenizer to tokeniz multi word expression

Tags: elasticsearch

i need to index some document with custom tokenizer.
my sample doc is look like this:

```
"I love to live in New York"
```

and list of expressions is:

```
["new york", "good bye", "cold war"]
```

is there any way to tokenize string normally but do not tokenize my dataset?

```
["I", "love", "to", "live", "in", "New York"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to give your data-set in the analyzer definition, as there is no pattern in your data set, that way these words would be excluded from your tokenization process, adding a working sample on your data-set would be helpful.